# jquery loading javascript file on dropdown change in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

basically what i am trying to do i have 2 div which are hidden plus a dropdown which will hide or show the particular div based on the selection criteria.What I have not achieve is that div1 should have English calender and div2 should have Arabic calender on the same page preloaded. So to achieve this how can i load the particular java script files in the page header on **the dropdown change**?

Edit:

Can we unload the script as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load javascript file in response to dropdown *change* event you can use [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$("#your_dropdown").change(function() {
    $.getScript('some_url_for_script_file.js');
})
```